# Return three lists with foreach loop in R

Tags: r, list, foreach

I've been struggling with the workings of foreach loops in R.
To speed up my code I'm trying to change my for loop into a foreach loop with %dopar%.

My goal is to end up with three lists of the same length, each filled with data frames that represent scores between two users (I'm comparing three different calculation methods).

My code used to be (very basic representation):

```
for (a in 1:5) {
   #Just creating some sample data    
   resultA <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 40, ncol = 3))
   resultB <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 40, ncol = 3))
   resultC <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 40, ncol = 3))
   names(resultA) <- c("User1", "User2", "score")
   names(resultB) <- c("User1", "User2", "score")
   names(resultC) <- c("User1", "User2", "score")

   resultA$User1 <- 1:40
   resultB$User1 <- 1:40
   resultC$User1 <- 1:40

   resultA$User2 <- 40:1
   resultB$User2 <- 40:1
   resultC$User2 <- 40:1

   resultA$score <- sample(40)
   resultB$score <- sample(40)
   resultC$score <- sample(40)



   ListA[[a]] <- resultA
   ListB[[a]] <- resultB
   ListC[[a]] <- resultC
}
```

With this code I do indeed get three nice lists with each containing 5 data frames.

Now I'm struggling to translate this to a foreach loop as it can only return one variable (correct me if I'm wrong). So I thought to put the lists in a master list, but then I have trouble getting a list with three sublists as result. Basically I want to append the three lists to themselves, but not to eachother. (So append resultA to ListA, resultB to ListB etc).

I've tried several options for .combine and .init but I can't seem to figure it out. With most functions for .combine I either end up with a huge matrix (which is bad because I can't distinguish the different scoring methods), or lists in lists in lists in lists in ...

EDIT:
I solved my problem by using the purrr::transpose() function to transpose the lists in lists. This resulted in one list with three lists (just the way I wanted it). Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will have more luck with a question if you have a minimally reproducible example. Please show us a minimumal example input, what code you've tried that isn't working, and what you expect the output to be. Right now your question is "How do you use %dopar% instead of any for loop that has 3 outputs?". A specific question is more likely to get strong responses.

Comment: It also may be useful to describe the problem at hand. Vectorization, rather than using parallel processing, may be more effective in speeding up your code.

Comment: I've tried to explain the problem a bit better (see original post). also @zack, I'm not sure how vectorization works. With the information above can you guess if that's going to be useful? In that case I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can convert your code in a nested foreach:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(2))
res_all <- foreach(a = 1:5) %:% foreach(b = 1:3) %dopar% {
  # Just creating some sample data    
  result <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 40, ncol = 3))
  names(result) <- c("User1", "User2", "score")

  result$User1 <- 1:40
  result$User2 <- 40:1
  result$score <- sample(40)

  result
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

You get a list of 5 lists of 3 data frames:

```
str(res_all)
```

If you want to invert the levels, you can e.g. use {purrr}:

```
str(purrr::transpose(res_all))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Although I thought I was doing something wrong in the foreach loop (which turned out I did right) I needed the proper transpose function at the end.