# Capturing parallelized R output types: Alternatives to bigstatsr that supports tibble like matrice and different variable types?

Tags: r, doparallel, bigstatsr

Previously I used `bigstatsr` to store computed values (double).

These values were computed in parallel using the `doParallel` package.

Now, I'm trying to use `bigstatsr` to store more complex objects. Typically in the form of list.

And only now I notice that `bigstatsr` do not support `list` object or even `character` type...

Are there any alternatives which I can use to store `list` objects?

Below a reproducible example.
Notice that `bigMatrice_sepalLength` can capture the numerical values
But `bigMatrice_sepalLengthWidth` fails to capture list of numerical values and `bigMatrice_species` couldn't store character values.

In my actual use case, I would need to parallelize some forecasting models.

Typically the outputs are list of values(historical, forecast), list of models, list of models parameters, etc.

Previously I can use bigstatsr because I only store the forecast values. Although this time around, I want to capture other information as well.

Thanks!

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

bigMatrice_sepalLength <- bigstatsr::FBM(nrow=nrow(iris),ncol=1)
bigMatrice_sepalLengthWidth <- bigstatsr::FBM(nrow=nrow(iris),ncol=1)
bigMatrice_species <- bigstatsr::FBM(nrow=nrow(iris),ncol=1)

cl_start <- Sys.time()
# set nb core to use
#no_cores <- detectCores() - 3
no_cores <- 1

# create cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, outfile = "")
# prepare cluster
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = 1:nb_forecast_level, .combine=cbind)  %dopar%  {
  bigMatrice_sepalLength[i,] <- iris[i,1]
  bigMatrice_sepalLengthWidth[i,] <- iris[i,c(1,2)] %>% list()
  bigMatrice_species[i,] <- iris[i,5]
}
stopCluster(cl)
stopImplicitCluster()
cl_end <- Sys.time()
(cl_runtime <- cl_end - cl_start)
as_tibble(bigMatrice_sepalLength[])
as_tibble(bigMatrice_sepalLengthWidth[])
as_tibble(bigMatrice_species[])
```

Results

```
> as_tibble(bigMatrice_sepalLength[])
# A tibble: 150 x 1
   value
   <dbl>
 1   5.1
 2   4.9
 3   4.7
 4   4.6
 5   5  
 6   5.4
 7   4.6
 8   5  
 9   4.4
10   4.9
# … with 140 more rows
> as_tibble(bigMatrice_sepalLengthWidth[])
# A tibble: 150 x 1
   value
   <dbl>
 1     0
 2     0
 3     0
 4     0
 5     0
 6     0
 7     0
 8     0
 9     0
10     0
# … with 140 more rows
> as_tibble(bigMatrice_species[])
# A tibble: 150 x 1
   value
   <dbl>
 1     0
 2     0
 3     0
 4     0
 5     0
 6     0
 7     0
 8     0
 9     0
10     0
# … with 140 more rows
```

Comment: You do not seem to work with very large data. So, what about directly returning the results from the parallel iterations rather than storing them?

Comment: This is just a reproducible example, so not sure how you deduce the size of the actual use case. I need to parallelize the code if I want to take advantage of multiple cores.

Not sure what you mean by 'directly' returning the results from parallel iterations vs storing them. I mean, I still need to somehow store the results of each parallel iteration for later consumption.

Comment: My understanding of using this bigstatsr matrix is mainly because of how it can handle parallel writing.

I'm not sure if a tibble can support multiple parallel writing, though. If I'm not mistaken, it'll be block by one program accessing it, the same way I a text file couldn't be edited if someone else is currently editing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return three lists with foreach loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894353/return-three-lists-with-foreach-loop-in-r)

Comment: @F.Privé thanks! I'm testing out the code without using bigstatsr. It seems I can return my preferred data format (tibble), then unnest them back to get the whole tibbles. But I'm yet to try out against the whole data. Will report back soon..

Comment: @F.Privé, while I like and prefer the idea of returning list() object, unfortunately my memory size couldn't cope with the memory size of the list(). So I still have to rely on bigstatsr to store the results because it has very little footprint on RAM.

Comment: You can always `saveRDS()` each part and combine the results later.

Comment: @F.Privé, that's the approach I'm using currently, though instead of RDS I use RData instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586733/saved-rdata-object-doesnt-appear-in-environment-after-load-call/

Comment: You should use RDS so that everything does not have the same name.

Comment: @F.Privé, not sure about that, I mean I can effectively save RData under different names